# Rails 7: How to check from outside transaction block if record was updated successfully

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've searched through the rails docs but not find any method which can check if record was corectly updated from outside transaction block because I dont want to put respond_to block into my transaction because it is bad practise. Is there any method like persisted? which I use with create/save method...

```
def update
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    address = Address.find_or_create_by(address_params)
    @invoice_account = InvoiceAccount.find_or_create_by(invoice_account_params
                                                          .merge({ :invoice_address_id => address.id }))
    @invoice = Invoice.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @invoice.update(invoice_params.merge({ purchaser_id: @invoice_account.id }))
  end

  respond_to do |format|
if @invoice.method `some method to check if invoice was updated`
      format.html { redirect_to invoice_url(@invoice), notice: "Invoice was successfully updated." }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @invoice }
    else
      format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think you are looking for the collection of methods provided by [`ActiveModel::Dirty`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) more specifically I think `previous_changes` might interest you. That being said if the `invoice` did not update successfully then the transaction would rollback so  I believe the result of the  `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` would be `nil` so maybe just capture the result and chekc against that instead?

Comment: @engineersmnky yes you right, i think better sollution is capture result of the transaction thank you

Comment: You can use a rescue too to check if data was saved successfully in the database, so the :unprocessable_entity status can be returned inside of this rescue. And you can add the `!` to update to raise an exception if an error occurs

Comment: @JonnathanCarrasco `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` swallows the error so I am not sure that would work [Source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb#L325)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just edit my code as bellow, capture result of the transaction to variable **is_updated**. When in transaction error occurred then **is_updated** would be **false** and changes are rolled back. If no error occurred **is_updated** **true**.

```
def update
  is_updated =
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    address = Address.find_or_create_by(address_params)
    @invoice_account = InvoiceAccount.find_or_create_by(invoice_account_params
                                                          .merge({ :invoice_address_id => address.id }))
    @invoice = Invoice.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @invoice.update(invoice_params.merge({ purchaser_id: @invoice_account.id }))
  end

respond_to do |format|
  if is_updated
    format.html { redirect_to invoice_url(@invoice), notice: "Invoice was successfully updated." }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @invoice }
  else
    format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end end
```

Comment: @engineersmnky I thought too but when I add breakpoint where is if statement then in debug console run is_updated.class returns FalseClass otherwise nil.class returns NilClass

Answer (score 0):

Calling `.update` on an ActiveRecord object will return `true` if it was able to store it to db or `false` if any error occurred.
I'd take advantage of that and store its result on a variable, like the following:

```
def update
  updated = false

  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    address = Address.find_or_create_by(address_params)
    @invoice_account = InvoiceAccount.find_or_create_by(invoice_account_params
                                                          .merge({ :invoice_address_id => address.id }))
    @invoice = Invoice.find_by_id(params[:id])
    updated = @invoice.update(invoice_params.merge({ purchaser_id: @invoice_account.id }))
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    if updated
      format.html { redirect_to invoice_url(@invoice), notice: "Invoice was successfully updated." }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @invoice }
    else
      format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think you could look into https://github.com/Envek/after_commit_everywhere through which you can use ```after_commit``` outside model.